# Creating a query which references a sub form from a sub form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to reference a control 'txtDescription' located on sub form 'frmStaticDataSkills02' from the sub form 'frmStaticDataSkills03'. Both of these forms sit in form 'frmStaticDataSkills01' which is a sub form of form 'frm_StaticData'.  Below is my string that is not working.

```
=[Forms]![frmStaticDataSkills01]![frmStaticDataSkills02].[Form]![txtDescription]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was a simple referencing issue where I wasn't successfully retrieving a control's contents which was located on a sub form nested three sub forms deep. The answer I posted solved my issue. PS- 'Maschere' means 'forms' in Italian (i am using the Italian version of Access. (I edited the answer to avoid confusion.

```
=[Maschere]![frm_staticdata]![frmStaticDataSkills01].[Form]![frmStaticDataSkills02].[Form]![txtDescription]
```

Comment: This could use a lot more description. What's `Maschere` and why wasn't it included in the question?

Comment: If this is the code that solved your issue, please add additional context and explanation to this post so future viewers of this answer will be able to use your information to solve their issues.

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Comment: Thank you to all! Sorry for the confusion. My problem was a simple referencing issue where I wasn't successfully retrieving a control's contents which was located on a sub form nested three sub forms deep. The answer I posted solved my issue.  PS- 'Maschere' means 'forms' in Italian (i am using the Italian version of Access. (I edited the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please take this text that you wrote in your comment and add it to the answer. That will make it more useful for others with a similar problem, and may even earn you some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

First go to the parent form of the form You are in and then go to the subform you want

Suppose you have a form with two subforms and you are in subform1 and want to access a textbox on subform2. Try the following:

```
Me.parent.subform2.form.textbox
```

You have to use the word "form" to specify the form object contained in frame subform2